# python does not match the output

Tags: python, arrays

i have a problem in my python code

```
def poison(health, turn, initial_turn, damage):
    if health <= 0:
        print(f"Turn : {turn - 1}, HP : 0")
        return
    if turn % 3 == initial_turn % 3:
        print(f"Turn : {turn}, HP : {health}")
        health -= damage
    poison(health, turn + 1, initial_turn, damage)

# APLIKASI
print(eval(input()))
```

but the output does not match what has been set

Your code did not pass this test case.

```
Input (stdin)
poison(40, 13, 13, 7)
Your Output (stdout)
Turn : 13, HP : 40
Turn : 16, HP : 33
Turn : 19, HP : 26
Turn : 22, HP : 19
Turn : 25, HP : 12
Turn : 28, HP : 5
Turn : 28, HP : 0
None
Expected Output
Turn : 13, HP : 40
Turn : 16, HP : 33
Turn : 19, HP : 26
Turn : 22, HP : 19
Turn : 25, HP : 12
Turn : 28, HP : 5
Turn : 29, HP : 0
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer
```

please help me

please help me, so that this code matches the output thank you

Comment: it's the '{turn - 1}' -> {turn } works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Works fine when done so not sure why you're struggling

Comment: thanks but to get rid of the output there is none Your code did not pass this test case.
Input (stdin)
poison(40, 13, 13, 7)
Your Output (stdout)
Turn : 13, HP : 40
Turn : 16, HP : 33
Turn : 19, HP : 26
Turn : 22, HP : 19
Turn : 25, HP : 12
Turn : 28, HP : 5
Turn : 29, HP : 0
None
Expected Output
Turn : 13, HP : 40
Turn : 16, HP : 33
Turn : 19, HP : 26
Turn : 22, HP : 19
Turn : 25, HP : 12
Turn : 28, HP : 5
Turn : 29, HP : 0
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer

Comment: My bad i forgot that that is due to your recursive function so that none is due to the function still carrying on once your stopping condition is reached so let me edit my answer

Comment: @jaden try it now

Comment: may I ask you to please rewrite my code? thank you

Comment: @jaden should be working fine

Comment: output Compile time error
Compile Message
Sorry: IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'while' statement on line 8 (Solution.py, line 9)
Exit Status
1

Comment: @jaden mate you can't just copy it straight, that warning means its not formatted properly, you have to make sure that the posion line is within the while statement not outside it. This is a homework type question and from what i can see there a whole lot of learning you got left to do

Comment: hey bro, still error

Comment: im beginner sorry

Comment: because there are #testcase 1,2 etc